# Want to change opencart url for all pages

Tags: php, .htaccess, opencart2.x

I want to change all opencart urls to seo friendly urls, I enabled seo url settings, and it's working fine, but I'm unable to chnage some of urls
From

```
/index.php?route=account/register
/index.php?route=account/login
/index.php?route=account/wishlist
/index.php?route=checkout/cart
/index.php?route=checkout/checkout
/index.php?route=information/contact
/index.php?route=account/return/add
/index.php?route=information/sitemap
/index.php?route=product/manufacturer
/index.php?route=account/voucher
/index.php?route=affiliate/account
/index.php?route=product/special
/index.php?route=account/account
/index.php?route=account/order
/index.php?route=account/newsletter
```

To

```
/register
/login
/wishlist
/cart
/checkout
/contact
/return/add
/sitemap
/manufacturer
/voucher
/account
/special
/account
/order
/newsletter
```

Already using SEO friendly urls.